# why after subtract mean and divided by standard deviation: the mean is not equal to 0 in R

Tags: r

I have a vector, t. I want to subtract with mean and divided by its deviation. While based on my expectation, the mean after that would be 0. However, it turns out some number closely to 0. I don't know what is going on here? Why it is not 0? Is it because of some 'magic' algorithm in R?

```
> t <- c(1,2,3,7)
> t 
[1] 1 2 3 7
> mean(t)
[1] 3.25
> t - mean(t)
[1] -2.25 -1.25 -0.25  3.75
> (t - mean(t))/sd(t)
[1] -0.85552774 -0.47529319 -0.09505864  1.42587956
> mean((t - mean(t))/sd(t))
[1] -1.734723e-17
```

Comment: That number is practically zero. Its because of the floating point precision. Recall that the numbers -0.85552774 for example can not be stored exactly in a computer. eg try doing `a <- 0.1 + 0.2; ` Now try `a == 0.3` It will never give you true, even though you know that `a is 0.3`

Comment: See the R FAQ: http://www.hep.by/gnu/r-patched/r-faq/R-FAQ_82.html